# Bundling angular ui project in springboot java project and accessing its UI

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

My project structure looks like:

```
my-app/pom.xml
my-app/my-app-service/pom.xml
my-app/my-app-ui/pom.xml
```

Inside my-app/pom.xml

```
...
<modules>
    <module>my-app-ui</module>
    <module>my-app-service</module>
</modules>
...
```

Inside my-app/my-app-service/pom.xml

```
...
<packaging>jar</packaging>
...
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/resources/public/</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/my-app-ui/dist/my-app-ui/</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

Inside my-app/my-app-ui/pom.xml

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v10.14.1</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>6.4.1</npmVersion>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm run build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>prod</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

Inside my-app/my-app-ui/dist/my-app-ui: `index.html`, `favicon.ico`, `all js` and `all .map` including `assets` folder

Inside SecurityConfig.java:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/rest/api/**").hasAnyAuthority(adminRead, adminReadWrite)
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/index.html").permitAll()
            .and().logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
...
}
```

Inside MyAppConfigSupport.java

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:swagger.properties")
@EnableSwagger2
public class MyAppConfigSupport extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
...
    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
...
}
```

Inside swagger.properties

```
springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/swagger
```

Inside application.properties

```
...
server.servlet.context-path=/my-app-services
...
```

1. I am running my jar as java -jar my-app-service.jar inside target folder.
2. I am able to access `https://localhost:8080/my-app-services/swagger-ui.html` and make all the REST calls.
3. I can see all the ui files inside `my-app-service/BOOT-INF/classes/resources/public/` folder.

Issue: I am unable to access `https://localhost:8080/my-app-services/` or `https://localhost:8080/my-app-services/index.html` error is `Whitelabel Error Page 404 not found`

Not sure where is the problem. Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had a similar problem, when I put the dist inside WEB-INF , then I was not able to access the index.html. I moved the dist outside of the WEB-INF and took the angular build using base-href property set. Then was able to get index.html. Haven't worked with spring boot. So cant exactly give an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to resolve my issue by below changes:

In SecurityConfig.java:

```
...
.antMatchers("/", "/*.html", "/*.js", "/*.map", "/assets/**", "/*.ico").permitAll()
...
```

Inside my-app/my-app-service/pom.xml

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-ui</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/static/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/my-app-ui/dist/my-app-ui/</directory>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>index.html</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-index-page</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/templates/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/my-app-ui/dist/my-app-ui/</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>index.html</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
...
```

Inside MyAppConfig.java

```
@Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
```

Inside my-app-ui/app/index.html

`<base href="/">` to `<base href="./">`